# creating variable using variable value as part of new variable name

Tags: shell, variable

I'm trying to create a new variable using the value of an existing variable as part of the variable name.

```
filemsg"$word1"=" "
```

I've also tried

```
filemsg$word1=" "

filemsg${word1}=" "
```

on all attempts I get the following when that line executes,

```
cicserrors.sh[45]: filemsgCICS= : not found [No such file or directory]
```

Comment: You may want to use hashes/associative arrays instead (or `perl` or other real programming language)

Answer (score 9):

Use `eval`:

```
filemsgCICS=foo
word1=CICS
eval "echo \"\$filemsg$word1\"" # => foo
eval "filemsg$word1=bar"
echo "$filemsgCICS" # => bar
```

but think twice if you really need it this way.

Another way in `ksh93` is to use [namerefs](http://oreilly.com/catalog/korn2/chapter/ch04.html#t4):

```
word1=CICS
nameref v=filemsg$word1
v="xxx" 
echo "$filemsgCICS" # => xxx
```

For even more nasty hacks like that look [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables).

Comment: @dazedandconfused: Naming variables on the fly is the sort of thing that will have programmers and code maintainers waiting for you in a dark alley for the purposes of beating you with surplus power cords. It's really not a best practice.

Comment: I agree with @Satanicpuppy: it is a practice to discourage, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

`export` does this far more safely than does `eval` because there is no danger of it executing shell code following a shell token. But it does `export` the variables so you can take it as you will.

```
export "filemsg$word1= "
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not *POSIX*, but in `bash` there's always `printf -v`, which prints not to standard output, but rather to whatever variable name follows `-v`:

```
x=foo; printf -v $x bar; echo $foo
```

Output:

```
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let filemsg"$word1"=" "
```

This may not be the best solution, but it has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filemsgCICS=foo

word1=CICS

ref_filemsg=filemsg$word1

echo ${!ref_filemsg} => foo
```

Comment: OK, that lets you *display* the value of the variable, but the question asks how to *create* the variable (i.e., to *assign* / *set* the value).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word1=CICS

var_name=filemsg$word1

eval ${var_name}="var_value"
```

To test:

```
echo $filemsgCICS ==> var_value
```