# Calling a function which calls another function with a for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am calling a function with a `for` loop and saving the returned value to a variable. When I run the code, I get a `command not found` error. What is wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

check_1()
{
    x_$1=$(check_2 $1)
}
check_2()
{
    ans=$((3+$1))
    echo $ans
}
for((i=1; i<=2;i++))
do
  check_1 $i
  tmp=x_$i
  echo ${!tmp}
done
```

If I run the script above I get:

```
sample.sh: line 5: x_1=4: command not found
sample.sh: line 5: x_2=5: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, as terdon says in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151580/977), use bash's associative arrays instead.

But, if you insist, and if you have a new enough bash, you can use a *nameref* (that's the magic word to search for in the manpage, by the way).

```bash
i=1
declare -n tmp="foo_$i" # this is the nameref line
tmp="fooval"            # actually sets $foo_1
echo "$foo_1"           # prints fooval
```

If inside a function, use `local -n` instead of `declare -n` to get a function-local variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't define variable names that way. You are trying to build your variable's name by using another variable's value: `x_$1=foo` and that won't work. A much better way would be to use an array instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_1()
{
    x[$1]=$(check_2 "$1")

}
check_2()
{
    ans=$((3+$1))
    echo "$ans"
}
for((i=1; i<=2;i++))
do
  check_1 "$i"
  echo "${x[$i]}"
done
```

The above returns:

```
$ sample.sh
4
5
```

Comment: but can i solve this issue without the use of array?

Comment: @shiva you really don't want to. What's the point of naming your variables that way? It might be possible with some very hard to read syntax but seriously, don't. That's precisely what arrays are for.

Comment: @shiva if you insist on doing it this way, see [Use a variable reference "inside" another variable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41406) and [creating variable using variable value as part of new variable name](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98419).

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't working with just math I'd suggest the only other *safe/portable* method I know of one that doesn't require very stringent testing:

```
var1=string1
export "$var1=string2"
echo "$var1"
echo "$string1"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string1
string2
```

But you are just working with math, and so you're problem is that you are `echo`ing the variable's value into a subshell when you should be concurrently defining it and evaluating it in the current shell.

```
i=0 ; until [ $((i=$i+1)) -ge 3 ]
do  echo "\$x_$i = $((x_$i=3+$i))"
done     
echo $x_1 $x_2
```

#### OUTPUT

```
$x_1 = 4
$x_2 = 5
4 5
```

So what you're doing is just math. The interesting thing about shell arithmetic is that you can use it to safely twice evaluate a variable in the current shell - no subshells.

[POSIX has this to say about it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04):

Arithmetic expansion provides a mechanism for evaluating an arithmetic expression and substituting its value. The format for arithmetic expansion shall be as follows:

> `$((expression))`
>
> The expression shall be treated as if it were in double-quotes, except that a double-quote inside the expression is not treated specially. The shell shall expand all tokens in the expression for parameter expansion, command substitution, and quote removal.

Perhaps more interestingly, it also has this to say:

> All changes to variables in an arithmetic expression shall be in effect after the arithmetic expansion, as in the parameter expansion `"${x=value}"`.
>
> If the shell variable `x` contains a value that forms a valid integer constant, optionally including a leading plus or minus sign, then the arithmetic expansions `"$((x))"` and `"$(($x))"` shall return the same value.

So if a variable is defined within the context of an arithmetic substitution, that definition persists in the current environment. Like:

```
echo $((x=1)); echo $x
1
1
```

But if you add to that the other parts - specifically that *the shell shall expand all tokens* **and** that *`"$((x))"` and `"$(($x))"` shall return the same value*. You might be able to see how the above `until` loop works.

So:

```
$((x_ #just a string
     $i #integer value
        = #assignment operator
          3 + #addition
              $i )) #same integer value
```

You see the shell has to expand the `$i` in both contexts - that of the variable shell token as a string before the assignment operator, and that of the integer value on which it performs the addition operation, the sum of which is assigned to `x_$i`.

Arrays can be handy, but, not counting one form, they are not portable and all come with their own implementation-specific snaffus. And besides - this is the answer to the question you asked.

This is why the following function works:

```
defv() {
    [ -n "${1##*[!0-9]*}" ] && # verify $1 is numeric only
    v=x_$1 &&                  # redefine caller loop var
    : $((x_$1=5+$1))           # : do nothing but expand arg
}

for v in 1 2 3 4 5             # init array
do  defv $v                    # defv() $indirection
    echo "$v = $(($v))"        # \$x_$indirection = $x_$indirection
done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
x_1 = 6
x_2 = 7
x_3 = 8
x_4 = 9
x_5 = 10
```

Your functions:

```
check_1()
{
    check_2 x_$1 $1
}
check_2()
{
    : $(($1=3+$2))
}
for((i=1; i<=2;i++))
do
  check_1 $i
  tmp=x_$i
  echo ${!tmp}
done
```

#### OUTPUT

```
4
5
```