# Local variable as a part of global one

Tags: bash, shell, variable

I have a question about something similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98419/creating-variable-using-variable-value-as-part-of-new-variable-name) question, but I need to call global variable depending on local one.

Say I want to pass either test, staging, or production as a variable to a script, I might do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
env=$1

export ENV_$env=some_param

echo $ENV_${env}
```

But the global variable seem not be retrieved at all:

```
# ./script.sh test
test
```

The use case for this script is to have provide isolation for processes to work in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing the `export` in the scope of a call to `eval`:

```
eval export ENV_${env}=some_param
```

This ensures that the shell expands `ENV_${env}` appropriately to one of your expected names, before trying to assign to it.

You'll also need to use `eval` when trying to retrieve the value stored in your variable:

```
eval echo \$ENV_$env
```

Note the backslash - it prevents the shell from attempting to expand the non-existent variable `$ENV_`, until after it has expanded the `$env` part with the builtin `eval`. It is the result of this expansion that is eventually passed to `echo`, which receives the full name of your dynamic variable, and expands it to yield the value you stored in it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553089/bash-dynamic-variable-names) I believe using

```
varname="ENV_$env"
echo ${!varname}
```

could be a solution.

Comment: I would think so too, but this didn't seem to work. I'm using bash 4.x.

Comment: @rahul it worked using bash 4.3.33, are you sure you had previously assigned a value to the variables "env" and "ENV_$env" ?