# Variable that is varying itself processing

Tags: shell-script, shell

i want to write a shell script

```
cd /dev
for hdd in sd*; do
    [ -f "$hdd" ] || continue
    status_$hdd=$(my_def_get_hddstaus "$hdd")       #my_def_get_hddstaus returns OK or FAIL randomly just to test   
done
```

i get error like

```
status_sda0=OK: command not found
status_sda1=FAIL: command not found
```

I want to record the value OK or Fail into these variable, I am using bash,
what I am doing wrong.

if I write `status_sda0=OK` in shell it record OK into `status_sda0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable name is not a static string (or rather: If the part before the `=` contains anything not allowed in a variable name) then the assignment is not recognized as such.

You need `eval`:

```
tmp_var="$(my_def_get_hddstaus "$hdd")"
eval status_$hdd=\""$tmp_var"\"
```

**edit**

You can `echo` the value using `eval` again or using indirection:

```
eval echo \"\$status_$hdd\"
```

or

```
var_name="status_$hdd"
echo "${!var_name}"
```

Comment: but now how would echo the value of variable dynamically $(status_$hdd). This is not working, Thanks for above solution atleast.

Comment: @user2642486 See my edit

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98419/creating-variable-using-variable-value-as-part-of-new-variable-name

I found in reference too 
eval "echo \"\$filemsg$word1\""

Thanks again